# date: illegal time format on OSX 10 on bash, but command works

Tags: macos, bash, date, format

I'm writing a bash script that reads and parses data from log lines, and it's trying to convert the format. The script is long, but I'll focus on the error:

```
if [[ $line == *"Marked: Malicious, To:"* ]]; then

QUEUE_ID=`awk ' {print $13}'  <<< $line | sed 's/,//g'` # QUEUE ID... index of the array

F_TIME["X$QUEUE_ID"]=`awk '{print $3}'  <<< $line ` # Hour
F_DAY["X$QUEUE_ID"]=`awk '{print $2}'  <<< $line ` # Day
F_MONTH["X$QUEUE_ID"]=`awk '{print $1}'  <<< $line ` # Month

#Procesing and obtaining the diff

F_FULLTIME["X$QUEUE_ID"]="${F_DAY["X$QUEUE_ID"]}-${F_MONTH["X$QUEUE_ID"]}-$year-${F_TIME["X$QUEUE_ID"]}" # creating the time in desired format

s=`date -j -f "%d-%b-%Y-%H:%M:%S"  "${F_FULLTIME[X$QUEUE_ID]}"   +%s` # ERROR LINE!! Doesn't work!

#s=`date -j -f "%d-%b-%Y-%H:%M:%S"  "2-Mar-2016-22:24:33"   +%s` # Test line

echo ".....${F_FULLTIME["X$QUEUE_ID"]}....2-Mar-2016-22:24:33...."

echo  "time $s ...\n";

fi
```

Test process: I comment the test line (marked on the script), and I try to do conversion to variable s. This is the output for each key:

```
Failed conversion of ``2-Mar-2016-20:30:03'' using format ``%d-%b-%Y-%H:%M:%S''
date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ...
        [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]

.....2-Mar-2016-20:30:03....2-Mar-2016-22:24:33....
```

Date is not taking the format. And as you can see, desired format and the format I have on the variable are pretty much same.

Test #2: I comment the error line, and I remove comment the test line. This is the result:

```
.....2-Mar-2016-22:06:10....2-Mar-2016-22:24:33....
time 1456953873 ...
```

Works perfectly. And of course text is aparently same as my variable on the first try.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks OK, although overly complex. Try this simplified version, which should be a little easier to debug. We're going to work with individual variables as much as possible, rather than array entries.

```
if [[ $line == *"Marked: Malicious, To:"* ]]; then

    # run `awk` once
    fields=$(awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $13}' <<< "$line")
    read f_month f_day f_time queue_id <<< "$fields"
    queue_id=${queue_id//,/}

    # Is the X really necessary?

    # F_TIME["X$queue_id"]=$f_time
    # F_DAY["X$queue_id"]=$f_day
    # F_MONTH["X$queue_id"]=$f_month

    #Procesing and obtaining the diff
    f_fulltime="$f_day-$f-month-$year-$f_time"
    # F_FULLTIME["X$queue_id"]=$f_fulltime

    s=$(date -j -f "%d-%b-%Y-%H:%M:%S" "$f_fulltime" )    
fi
```

Some questions to ask:

1. What are the exact values of `queue_id`, `f_time`, `f_day`, and `f_month`? Use, e.g., `printf '%s' "$queue_id" | hexdump -C` to see if
   there are any hidden characters from `$line` that are confusing `date`.
2. Can you reproduce the problem by hardcoding the values of the pieces instead of just `f_fulltime` itself?
3. Can you reproduce the problem by hard-coding the value of `line` just prior to the call to `awk`?

Comment: Hi:Thanks for your help. queue_id is a alphanumeric code that I read before  in the script. Example "3qFnGR2Gdrz4p24D".f_time, f_day and f_month are the data values for this entry log, taken from $line.

Comment: About your comment #2: If I hardcode f_fulltime everything works fine!:                                               #Procesing and obtaining the diff
    #f_fulltime="$f_day-$f_month-$year-$f_time"
 f_fulltime="2-Mar-2016-22:24:33"
    # F_FULLTIME["X$queue_id"]=$f_fulltime

    s=$(date -j -f "%d-%b-%Y-%H:%M:%S" "$f_fulltime" )

Comment: About #3.. I didn't try since seems like the error is in #2

Comment: Extra that I notice now.. This script read lines.. and takes queue_id as the key of an associate array. The final purpose is: I read all the once, I extract the queue_id as key. I store some variables of the log line (day, hour, month etc), and I store them on separated associative arrays.Therefore I need to store all info into the VARIABLE["X$queue_id"]=VALUE. For this part it's ok since I'm calculating the time on the current fulltime, day, time values.. but I need to do same stuff for the starting time that occurs on the pasts loops. This is why I need to map same event with the queue_id...

Comment: So finally to your question "# Is the X really necessary?" yes.. if not queue_id is taking as "octal" as I read when I tried to fix this issue before..

Comment: The X isn't necessary; you need to declare your arrays as an associative arrays with `declare -A` to prevent the index from being treated as an arithmetic expression. Adding the X just converts the number to an identifier whose value is used as the index. (And since `X0821` or whatever is probably not defined, they all evaluate to 0, so you're just constantly overwriting the first element to the array.)

Answer (score 0):

Well... I've cleaned the script, removed extra variables, declared arrays, and I found where the error comes from. But not sure why. The error comes from the variable `$year`.

This is defined as:

```
year=`date +"%Y"`
```

Then.. when I tried this conversion:

```
s_fulltime["X$queue_id"]="$day-$month-$year-$time" >> date: illegal time format
```

But.. if I harcode "2016" then..

```
year="2016"
```

All works fine.

Why?